# Android: programmatically creating two columns in a table

Tags: android, android-layout

```
showtimeTable = new TableLayout(this);
         showtimeTable.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

         for(int i=0;i<object.dateList.size();i++){
              /* Create a new row to be added. */
              TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
              tr.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                   /* Create testview to be the row-content. */
              mytext = new TextView(this);
             mytext.setText(object.dateList.get(i).getTextDate());
             mytext.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
             mytext.setTextAppearance(this, R.style.detaileventDate);
                   tr.addView(mytext);



                   time = new TextView(this);
                   time.setText(object.dateList.get(i).getTime());
                   time.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                   time.setTextAppearance(this, R.style.detaileventTime);
                    tr.addView(time);
         /* Add row to TableLayout. */
         showtimeTable.addView(tr,new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                   LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                   LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
         }


         layout.addView(showtimeTable);
```

I have this table all setup, but the two textfields are hugging each other. What I want to achieve is the appearance of two columns and have the time textfield on the right side.

I tried changing the margins in their respective Styles but that doesnt affect it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use padding here. It will make padding of the Text view inside the table row. I have tried to do it with your code and just added some test lines:

```
mytext.setPadding(20, 3, 20, 3);
time.setPadding(20, 3, 20, 3);
```

It worked fine. Moreover, you can use "Gravity" for your purposes. See and example here: http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tablelayout.html

Answer (score 0):

Table layout does not have concept of columns but you can add multiple views in table row by defining different width of those views.

Following code will specify size of column depending on specified colSpan value.

```
int COL_COUNT=2;
int mScreenWidthInDp = getScreenWidthInDip(activityContext);

private View getColumnItem(String colText, int colSpan) {

        View view = mActivity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.table_column_view, null);
        TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tablet_title);



        textView.setText(colText);
        int columnWidth = (mScreenWidthInDp / COL_COUNT) * span;
        TableRow.LayoutParams params = new TableRow.LayoutParams(columnWidth, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1);
        params.span = colSpan;
        view.setLayoutParams(params);
        return view;
    }


    public static int getScreenWidthInDip(Activity context) {
        if (mScreenWidthInDp == 0) {
            WindowManager wm = context.getWindowManager();
            DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
            wm.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
            int screenWidth_in_pixel = dm.widthPixels;
            float screenWidth_in_dip = screenWidth_in_pixel / dm.density;
            mScreenWidthInDp = (int) screenWidth_in_dip;
        }
        return mScreenWidthInDp;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can set layout weight parameter for the table row. This will arrange the childrens accordingly.
mytext.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,1f));

The final parameter is the layout weight